# Python method equivalent to racket's build-vector

Tags: python, list, vector, lambda

I am looking for a method that can do exactly that in python but with lists instead of vectors:

```
(build-vector n (lambda _ (build-vector n (lambda _ (my-random n)))))
```

This is what I came up with (but with a 2D list)

```
   table = []
    for i in range(n):
        trans = [(random n) for i in range(n)]
        table = table + [trans]
```

But they give different results. I'm not sure where it goes wrong, any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with racket but `build-vector` looks like a list comprehension or `map`:

```
Racket: (build-vector n proc)
Python: [proc(i) for i in range(n)]
Python: map(proc, range(n))
```

So it looks like you are building a nxn matrix of random numbers:

Racket:

```
(build-vector n (lambda _ (build-vector n (lambda _ (my-random n)))))
```

Python:

```
[[my_random(n) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

So using `random.randrange` for `my_random`:

```
>>> from random import randrange as my_random
>>> n = 5
>>> [[my_random(n) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
[[1, 2, 2, 0, 3],
 [3, 0, 2, 1, 3],
 [3, 1, 3, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 2, 4, 4],
 [1, 0, 1, 4, 1]]
```